# How to redirect a button to a different page based on used login on Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, authentication

I have a button that I have that leads users to a page on WordPress called `/portfolio/`, so is there a way that I can redirect users to the `/registration/` page until their logged in?

I'm using a plugin on WordPress that uses the below code to change the menu per user logged in/logged out.

```
function my_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {

if( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
    $args['menu'] = 'logged-in';
} else { 
    $args['menu'] = 'logged-out';
} 
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

Is there a way that I can use the `if( is_user_logged_in() )` to do the same with a redirect? I can't seem to lock the page down to all users.

Answer (score 1):

You could so something like this?

```
if(!is_user_logged_in()) {
    //If user not logged in     
    echo "<script> location.href='http://somesite/registration/'; </script>";
}
```

This should work if you arent using jquery as its JavaScript.

Comment: I am not using jQuery or Javascript at all, so this might actually work really well! When the user will click on a button, it will redirect them to the registration page unless their logged in.

Comment: Sadly it didn't work :( - I'll have to look at another alternative.